# PowerShell Script Starts Adding Blank Lines After 100+ Lines of Output?

Tags: powershell

I seem to have encountered a weird bug, or I've missed something in my script.

In my scripts, I'm showing progress with a faux progress bar function. It works by updating the same line of the console repeatedly, mimicking a progress bar. See the function below:

```
# Update-Progress-Bar : v1.0 : 2013-07-29
# Displays a percentage bar. Meant to be used repeatedly to update the same console line (giving the appearance of incrementing progress).
# - $Percentage : Determines how much progress is shown on the bar.
# - $Message : The message that accompanies the progress bar.
function Update-Progress-Bar ($Percentage, $Message){
    # Save the current cursor position so we can come back later.
    $CursorPosition = $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition

    # Convert the percentage into a proper progress bar.
    $ProgressBarMax = "20"
    $ProgressBarCount = [Math]::Floor([Decimal]($Percentage / 5))
    $ProgressBar = ("#" * $ProgressBarCount) + (" " * ($ProgressBarMax - $ProgressBarCount))

    # Change the format of the percentage depending on length.
    switch ($Percentage.Length){
        1 {$Percentage = "  " + $Percentage + "%"}
        2 {$Percentage = " " + $Percentage + "%"}
        default {$Percentage = $Percentage + "%"}
    }

    # Trim or pad the message as necessary.
    $MessageMaxLength = "50"
    if ($Message.Length -gt $MessageMaxLength){ $Message = $Message.Remove($MessageMaxLength) }
    else { $Message = $Message + (" " * ($MessageMaxLength - $Message.Length)) }    

    # Display our progress bar, percentage, and message.
    Write-Host -nonewline -ForeGroundColor Blue "[$ProgressBar] $Percentage"
    Write-Host " | $Message"

    # Revert back to the original cursor position.
    $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $CursorPosition
}
```

For whatever reason, after working for about 100+ records (I'm using this as part of a script where I'm regularly performing actions against 1000s of machines), it starts performing double line breaks, which ruins the functionality of the progress bar. So I end up with this...

```
[ 126 / 2275 ] ComputerName1
[                    ]   0% | Verifying network connectivity...

[##                  ]  10% | Verifying file system access...

[####                ]  20% | Determining installed operating system...

[######              ]  30% | Executing action...

[####################] 100% | Action Completed



[ 127 / 2275 ] ComputerName2
[                    ]   0% | Verifying network connectivity...

[##                  ]  10% | Verifying file system access...

[####                ]  20% | Determining installed operating system...

[######              ]  30% | Executing action...

[####################] 100% | Action Completed
```

When I should have....

```
[ 126 / 2275 ] ComputerName1
[####################] 100% | Action Completed

[ 127 / 2275 ] ComputerName2
[####################] 100% | Action Completed
```

Any thoughts on this issue and a possible workaround?

**EDIT #1:** Is it possible that this is happening when I hit the buffer height limit of the console (as in, it starts discarding the old lines of output)?

**EDIT #2:** I have confirmed that this issue goes away if I increase the buffer width and height of my console window. I'm still not sure how to workaround this bug though. Thoughts?

Comment: I never heard about using such hack `$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition`, but you may be right with your assumption. As a side note, is there any reason why you don't want to use a [native progress bar available in Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script.aspx)?

Comment: @Neolisk, I actually didn't know about the native progress bar option, though I recognize it from other plug-ins. I'll have to see if it I still like the functionality, but it seems like I'm still going to keep hitting some sort of buffer limit, unless I choose to stop displaying "historic" progress at all.

Comment: I just hope they took care of known issues with their native progress bar. Did not use it much though, probably because the nature of my tasks never required it.

Comment: Can I see the code that generates the percentage variable your passing in?

Comment: @Cole9350 I'm actually defining it manually-- the tasks I'm performing aren't something that I need to track exact progress for. The command is called like this-- Update-Progress-Bar "20" "Determining installed operating system..."

Comment: I don't get how buffer size would matter, since your printing on the same line every time. I cant recreate the error with this piece of code, seems to run fine... `for($i=0;$i -le 1200; $i++) {
    for($j=0;$j -le 100; $j++) {
        Update-Progress-Bar "$j" "String$i"
    }
}`   .... The native progress bar is a lot easier and looks nicer too :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified this bug on my own machine.  As soon as you start wrapping the buffer, -nonewline fails to live up to its task.

You can do a few things as a workaround:

1) Programmatically increase the BufferSize to a fixed size

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(120, 5000)
```

2) Clear the screen every so often, perhaps every 100 nodes or after each node if you don't need to follow the output

3) Clear the screen only when you've nearly reached the buffer limit

```
if($Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition.Y -gt ($Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Height - 5)) {cls}
```

4) Clear only old parts of the screen buffer by temporarily reducing the size of the buffer.  I used your function, untouched (except renaming to remove the second "-").  With the screen buffer at 100, the odd behavior would start at number 50 (2 output lines per loop)

```
49 / 2000
[####################] 100% | FINAL
50 / 2000
[####                ]  20% | First
[########            ]  40% | Second
[############        ]  60% | Third
[################    ]  80% | Fourth
[####################] 100% | FINAL

51 / 2000
[####                ]  20% | First
[########            ]  40% | Second
[############        ]  60% | Third
[################    ]  80% | Fourth
[####################] 100% | FINAL
```

But with the BufferSize switching, I made it all the way to 2000/2000 without a hitch

```
1998 / 2000
[####################] 100% | FINAL
1999 / 2000
[####################] 100% | FINAL
2000 / 2000
[####################] 100% | FINAL

$range = 1..2000
```

Test code below:

```
foreach($i in $range)
{
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(120, 3000)

    Write-Host
    Write-Host $i "/ 2000"

    Update-ProgressBar "20" "First"
    Update-ProgressBar "40" "Second"
    Update-ProgressBar "60" "Third"
    Update-ProgressBar "80" "Fourth"
    Update-ProgressBar "100" "FINAL"

    $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(120, 2990)
}
```

Realistically, you could combine 3 and 4 so that you only clear the old parts of the buffer when it is nearly full.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bug and finding a solution.

I was able to combine steps 3 and 4 successfully-- so I've marked this answer as correct.